# VB.Net Regular Expressions with Zeros

Tags: regex

I have a Validator that validate a maskedtextbox with mask of "000 000".If MaskedTextBox.text is nothing the validator does not match and thus preventing blank data, works it fine. But I need Regular Expression for matching...

**1) Match only if MaskedTextBox.text.length is " 6 " numbers

2) Each & every number in MaskedTextBox.text can have 0-9**

It may have cases like "010 000", "001 000", "011 000","000 100", "000 010", "000 001" etc...

Also I am new to Regex and i have only two or three days with it.

Please Help me.... Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this regex:

```
^\d{6}$
```

It uses begin and end anchors to ensure it captures the entire string.

If you are trying to allow for a space in the middle, then use this:

```
^\d{3} \d{3}$
```

Comment: Sorry, ur code not giving match for Zero Started entries. For "100 000" its OK, but "010 000" Preventing. It may have cases of 001, 011 etc...

Comment: It allows any digit in any of the six spots. Maybe that leading zero is being trimmed before your regex check? Also, are you trying to match only `0` or `1` in each spot, or any numeric digit?

Comment: No, it can have any number. But it seems like my VB's Problem or I am not sure. I found Ur code is absolutely correct. I may try.